# Why was this question down voted?

Tags: discussion

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31440/wpdb-usage-how-do-i-get-items-when-querying-product-posts

Comment: You already asked this question in a comment on the original question.  Yes, it's bad form that someone downvoted without leaving an explanation, but please don't clutter the Meta list with this extra commentary.

Comment: I did ask within the question itself, but I thought it more appropriate after the fact to ask the question within meta. My apologies for "cluttering" up the site.

I did not find it to be extra commentary.

Comment: Please read [the FAQs for the Meta site](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). Questions here should be pertaining to the site itself, not requests for clarification regarding down voting.

Comment: @EAMann I disagree, as for me this is perfectly fine issue for meta. Meta exists for anything that is related to main site but doesn't belong on it, seeking to clarify site mechanics and principles certainly belongs here.

Comment: I think a "what are reasons for downvoting" question would be appropriate. Or something addressing broader mechanics.  But this question as asked, with only a link back to a question on the main site, isn't asking about site mechanics or principles or prompting a meta-level discussion about them. It feels very much like a "solve my specific problem" question, but asked in regards to a main site question rather than a WP site.

Comment: I was addressing the broader mechanics of why the question linked would have been downvoted. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Regardless, I'm sure we all have better things to do than to go back and forth over this topic any longer. I'll do my best to ask appropriate questions in the appropriate way & place from now on. Perhaps there should be a "redemption" feature added that would allow someone to regain their reputation points losses from asking a "inappropriate" question.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the person who downvoted answers here, it's not really possible to tell precisely.

In general - questions that are very specific to plugins are not overly favored. It's not that they are "bad" questions... But they are hard (or impossible) to answer without as specific expertise with that plugin. So they float around by hundreds and haunt site as unanswered.

Take it as *someone* didn't like the question, not as the whole site is out to get you.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: I think I would agree with @Devise that the question, if well-written, may be well within the scope of WPSE. I tend to shy away from flagging/down-voting purely on the basis of a question being Plugin support, because the line is incredibly unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I've neither up- nor down-voted the question, but if I *were* to down-vote, it would be due to question *quality* rather than scope*.

You state that the question has to do with `wpdb()`, but you don't actually reference this function within your example code. Also, as @EAMann pointed out, you didn't describe your *expected* output, and how the *actual* output differs from expected. Thus, the question is rather difficult to answer, as-is.

**ironic, I know*

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this would be the best place to suggest something like this, but here it goes :)

In my short time being here I've seen several similar questions being asked. (also, I've seen several questions up and down voted for no apparent reason)

One of the solutions would of course be to simply moderate all votes. Or to have things listed somewhere, and make penalties when really needed.

But the easier, and more fair solution would probably be to include/force some kind of input field when voting.

Comment: _include/force some kind of input field when voting_ there is input - comment field under everything.